# Which film was the first to show us the face of God?

Tags: first-appearance, analysis

There have been a lot of greek myth Gods depicted in film. Which film was the first to show us the face of the Christian God Jehovah?

Comment: Monty Python and the Holy Grail?

Comment: Personally, I was hoping for "Time Bandits" :)

Comment: Dogma - Alanis Morrisette

Comment: Jehova? That's the name for god in the Judaism religion. In christianity, god is just... god (and different in different languages)

Comment: Well, according to Christian tradition, YHWH (sometimes written as Jehovah) is the same as the Christian God. Jesus was Jewish, after all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The earliest reference I could find is [*The Green Pastures*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Green_Pastures_%28film%29) (1936). The story relates "portrays episodes from the Old Testament as seen through the eyes of a young African-American child in the Depression-era South, who interprets The Bible in terms familiar to her."  The film is based on the 1930 play of the same name.

The next one I could find is [*The Old Grey Hare*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Old_Grey_Hare) (1944) in which the titular character is the beloved Bugs Bunny and the voice of God was provided by Mel Blanc, famous for doing the voices of Bugs Bunny and many other Looney Tune characters.

Comment: +1 for The Green Pastures.  The Old Grey Hare has 'the voice of god' in the wikipedia article - does it show a face?

Comment: @iandotkelly: I'm not sure of Old Grey Hare shows the face, I don't think so.  The main reason I included it was because of the humor of thinking of Mel Blanc, so famous from Looney Tunes and the Jack Benny Show, doing God's voice.

Comment: Not sure if Jesus is counted, but he is depicted at the end of Birth of a Nation.

Comment: And here's a [couple](http://www.classicfilmguide.com/index96aa.html) of [photos](http://i147.photobucket.com/albums/r312/jbrewerbucket/delawdabmpddd.jpg) of Rex Ingram playing "De Lawd" in *The Green Pastures* (1936). [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0026790/) lists 351 appearances of the character God, with seven from before *The Green Pastures*, but they're false listings: either it's just a lord (not The Lord) or someone's papa (not The Papa).

Comment: Mel Blanc as God? Now I *have* to see this movie!